# shell bash - return code

Tags: bash, shell, return

Is it possible to run a command to redirect output and standard error in a file and know the return code of the command ?

```
./COMMANDE.sh 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG_DIRECTORY/$LOG_FILE
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "KO"
    exit 1
fi
```

Currently, I get the return code of the `tee` command, I want to recover that of `COMMANDE.sh`.

Answer (score 3):

You want `PIPESTATUS`.

```
./COMMANDE.sh 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG_DIRECTORY/$LOG_FILE
if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} = 0 ]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "KO"
    exit 1
fi
```

The index into the array (`[0]`) is the index of the command in the pipe chain just executed (`./COMMANDE.sh`). `${PIPESTATUS[1]}` would be the `tee`.

Comment: @davidcondrey pointed out that `zsh` has a similar construct `pipestatus` that starts counting array indices at 1.